# Download multiple files from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with rows, where each row has a link to download a file from database.

I'm using the following code to download a `file(byte[])` from db.

```
Page.Response.AddHeader("....");                       
Page.Response.Charset = ""; 
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Page.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])reader["FileData"]); 
Page.Response.End();
```

But my problem is when the user clicks on one to download the entire page response stops and the user cannot click any button or link on the page because of `Page.Response.End();`

I need to have a way to do multiple downloads on the same page in the same gridview and end user need to ask where to save and again click another file to download again and again.

Comment: Does setting the target attribute of the link to "_blank", so that it doesn't attempt to start the download in the same window help?

Comment: More info, please. For example, show GridView handler that downloads a file

Comment: No just forget the gridview download,imagine there are more than one download buttons in one page,need to download one by one with out page.response ending.

Comment: @kamesh well, you want to create something like a download query?

Comment: Are you trying to do multiple downloads at the same time from a single HTTP request? Or do you expect the user to click the button once per download? The second one should be pretty easy to do. I suspect you're ending the response before the entire page has rendered or you have an UpdatePanel confusing things.